# Can you factor out a derivative inside an integral?

Tags: calculus

I want to know if the following operation is legit and if no, why not?

$$\text Let\ u= f(x) \ and\ v=g(x) $$

$$
\int uv' \ =?  \ \  v\int u
$$

Basically, can I take the derivative out? (Since integration is opposite to defferentiation)

Or perhaps that is not legit due to f(x) and g(x) being to different funcitons, can I do it if is the same function?

$$
\int uu' \ =?  \ \  u\int u
$$

Comment: No, you can't. However, note that for the second integral, the answer is straightforward: $\;\displaystyle \int uu'=\tfrac12 u^2+\text{cst}$.

Comment: $\int_a^b u(x) v'(x) \, dx    \ =\ \Big[u(x) v(x)\Big]_a^b - \int_a^b u'(x) v(x) \, dx
   \ =\ u(b) v(b) - u(a) v(a) - \int_a^b u'(x) v(x) \, dx $ is called [*integration by parts*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts).

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can always just try some functions to see if it works. What happens if you let $f(x) = x$ and $g(x) = x$?

In general, it is true that
\begin{equation*}
 \int uv' \,\mathrm dx = uv - \int u'v\,\mathrm dx
\end{equation*}
(this is called [integration by parts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts), and it is basically just a consequence of the product rule for differentiation but going the other way) and also that
\begin{equation*}
 \int uu'\,\mathrm dx = \tfrac 12 u^2 + C
\end{equation*}
which you can verify by differentiation.

Answer (score 2):

No. You could do that for $\int_a^b v'(x) dx\ = v(x)|_{a}^{b}$

But not if there is another value in the integral.

Counter example : $\int x \cdot ln'(x) dx = \int x \cdot \frac{1}{x} dx =\int 1 dx  \neq ln(x)\cdot\int x dx $

You might want to take a look at integration by parts

Answer (score 0):

I presume the first isn't the case, since if we had an integral like $$ \int xe^x$$ 
we would need to use the chain rule and we can't simply take out $$ e^x $$
in front of the integral. But is there any operation we can do to factor out a derivative?

Comment: I don't think the chain rule will work for your example `:)`

Answer (score 0):

No.  What you do have, with integration by parts, is: $\int uv'=uv-\int u'v$.

So for a counterexample, we just need $v\int u\ne uv-\int u'v$.  For instance, take $u=1,v=x$.